# Can I stop MySQL from indexing particular values?

Tags: mysql

Suppose I have a MySQL (InnoDB) table like this

```
CREATE TABLE Item (id INT, ..., score INT, INDEX (score));
```

Because of the application logic, everything starts out with a score of 1, shortly afterwards each Item will get a different score (with relatively few collisions after that so the index of non-1 values should be fairly balanced).

This is a write-frequently table. I am concerned that as the database scales, the index will get thrashed, specifically the bucket of items with `score=1`. I don't understand the full implications with regards to fragmentation and clustering, and I can't test this properly until we *actually* scale up the hardware.

**Is there a way to tell MySQL to not insert any records into the index for this given special value?**

There are never any queries with `WHERE score=1`, the "hardest" required query would be `SELECT ... WHERE score>lower_limit ORDER BY score`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use [`Filtered Indexes` or `Partial Indexes`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280372.aspx). Unfortunately [there's no such an option in MySQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/106589/to-have-postgresql-like-partial-index-in-mysql-5-5).

If I had to do this, I would create a second table named `Item_score` with an index on score and containing only Items with a value higher than 1.